# Two clocks side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this has been asked a million times already, i'm quite new with this so it's difficult for me to understand some of the responses. I am trying to have two analog clocks side by side, ticking away. I am not sure why this code isn't showing that.

I would like to make a simple website of multiple timezones shown on each clock, but for now they can all be the same time.

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`;
  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 90;
  minsHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;
  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins / 60) * 30) + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
}
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

```css
html {
  background: #018DED url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock,
.clocktwo {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF, inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face,
.clock-facetwo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand,
.handtwo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* transform-origin will allow us to rotate the clock hands along the x axis, so it */
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clocktwo">
  <div class="clock-facetwo">
    <div class="handtwo hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="handtwo min-hand"></div>
    <div class="handtwo second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple (two to be exact) of each (second, min, hour) clock 'hands'. But you use `querySelector` which will only select the first (from top to bottom of the HTML structure) element it finds.

What you need to do, is to select all of them using *e.g.* `querySelectorAll` and then loop over them.

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelectorAll('.second-hand');
const minsHand = document.querySelectorAll('.min-hand');
const hourHand = document.querySelectorAll('.hour-hand');

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = ((seconds / 60) * 360) + 90;
  secondHand.forEach(sec => sec.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`);
  const mins = now.getMinutes();
  const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + ((seconds / 60) * 6) + 90;
  minsHand.forEach(min => min.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`);
  const hour = now.getHours();
  const hourDegrees = ((hour / 12) * 360) + ((mins / 60) * 30) + 90;
  hourHand.forEach(hour => hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`);
}
setInterval(setDate, 1000);
setDate();
```

```css
html {
  background: #018DED url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock,
.clocktwo {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #EFEFEF, inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face,
.clock-facetwo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand,
.handtwo {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /* transform-origin will allow us to rotate the clock hands along the x axis, so it */
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clocktwo">
  <div class="clock-facetwo">
    <div class="handtwo hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="handtwo min-hand"></div>
    <div class="handtwo second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for your help on this!

Comment: @Conor glad i could help . Please do not forget to rate and accept the answer. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` to get reference to all elements.

Then you can set the transform values for each element like this:

```
const bothSecondHands = document.querySelectorAll('.second-hand');
bothSecondHands.forEach(secondHand => secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`);
```